# How to disable right click option and youtube water mark logo from Youtube Video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any solution to Disable right Click option and Remove bottom right water mark logo from Youtube Video ? I'm tried after searching GOOGLE. Can anyone tell me about it ?

**Thank You.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the `modestbranding` parameter:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding